# How to test params on a ajax post method?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I currently have the following code:

```
$.post( "/conversation/delete", { usrId: '<?php echo $conUser->getId(); ?>', conId: '<?php echo     $otherConversation->getId(); ?>' })
    .done(function () {
         $('.<?php echo $otherConversation->getId().'-trash-can'; ?>').closest('li').remove();
         console.log({ usrId: '<?php echo $conUser->getId(); ?>', conId: '<?php echo $otherConversation->getId(); ?>' });
    });
```

And in my controller I have the following:

```
public function delete($args=array()) {

    //$conId = $args['conId'];

    var_dump($args);die;

}
```

I am trying to var_dump all the arguments that I am sending through the ajax post method. How can I test this? cause right now I am getting nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use-

```
.done(function (data) {
```

In the `data` you'll get the response back, whatever your php script is printing.

Comment: I am returning front he controller the $args, and the data comes back empty. There is nothing

Comment: You mean `return`? that wont work, use `print_r` or `echo` to get the result back in the callback